# How can I create an image carousel in c# using xna?

Tags: c#, image, xna

I am looking to create a 3D image carousel using the xna game studio. I cant find any relevant tutorials on the matter. Flash or silverlight are recommended but our entire project is being developed in c# using xna! Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to create a very complex user control.  We can't tell you how to do this.

How I would go about this is I'd study the free WPF/silverlight versions out there (I'm familiar with WPF so I wouldn't bother with flash versions), then try to apply that in XNA.  Obviously I'd have to use controls available within XNA.  So I'd have to sit down and learn D3D, as I'd probably have to use that to implement the visual aspects of the control.

Answer (score 0):

The main ingredients off the top of my head:

- create a mesh of surfaces representing the images, textured with the actual images
- add lighting to the scene
- hook up input ( mouse, Xbox controller, whatever) in order to rotate the 3D scene

You should find good tutorials on all these topics around the net. I can recommend [Ziggyware](http://www.ziggyware.com/) as a starting point.